# change class name to a new random class name

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and programming in general.

I have 20 `div` elements, which share the same class name. I am applying randomly a new class to this 20 divs from a list array of 40 class name.

How can I apply UNIQUE class name to my divs?

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__grid">
      <div id="square1" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square2" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square3" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square4" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square5" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square6" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square7" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square8" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square9" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square10" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square11" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square12" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square13" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square14" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square15" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square16" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square17" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square18" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square19" class="box0"></div>
      <div id="square20"class="box0"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far, I set up an array with my class name:

```
var arrayClass = ["box1","box2","box3","box4","box5",
                  "box6","box7","box8","box9","box10",
                  "box11","box12","box13","box14","box15",
                  "box16","box17","box18","box19","box20",
                  "box21","box22","box23","box24","box25",
                  "box26","box27","box28","box29","box30",
                  "box31","box32","box33","box34","box35",
                  "box36","box37","box38","box39","box40"];
```

Then I manage to have a list of 20 random `arrayClass`:

```
var randomClassList = [];
for (var index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
  randomClassList.push(arrayClass[Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayClass.length)]);
```

and push it into my HTML:

```
square1.className = randomClassList[0]
square2.className = randomClassList[1]
square3.className = randomClassList[2]
square4.className = randomClassList[3]
square5.className = randomClassList[4]
square6.className = randomClassList[5]
square7.className = randomClassList[6]
square8.className = randomClassList[7]
square9.className = randomClassList[8]
square10.className = randomClassList[9]
square11.className = randomClassList[10]
square12.className = randomClassList[11]
square13.className = randomClassList[12]
square14.className = randomClassList[13]
square15.className = randomClassList[14]
square16.className = randomClassList[15]
square17.className = randomClassList[16]
square18.className = randomClassList[17]
square19.className = randomClassList[18]
square20.className = randomClassList[19]
```

Comment: Just remove the class name from `arrayClass` after adding it to `randomClassList`

Answer (score 0):

```
const classes = [...Array(40)].map((_, i) => `box${i + 1}`) // generate a new array of length 40 whose elements are `box(index+1)`
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.box0') // pick all the elements which have the default 'box0' class


squares.forEach(square => { // iterate over the squares array
    const randomClassIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length) // pick a random index in the classes array
    square.classList.replace('box0', classes[randomClassIndex]) // add the chosen random class to the square's classList

    classes.splice(randomClassIndex, 1) // remove the chosen class from the array
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the element from the array once it's picked:

```
const randomClassList = [];
for (var index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayClass.length);
  randomClassList.push(arrayClass[randomIndex]);
  arrayClass.splice(randomIndex, 1);
}
```

Or, even better, without a `for` loop:

```
const randomClassList = Array.from({ length: 20}, () => {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayClass.length);
  randomClassList.push(arrayClass[randomIndex]);
  arrayClass.splice(randomIndex, 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomClassList = [];

while(randomClassList.length < 20){
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*40) + 1;
    if(randomClassList.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    // randomClassList[randomClassList.length] = 'box' + randomnumber;
    randomClassList.push('box' + randomnumber);
}
```

Comment: Interested as to why you've chosen to use `arr[index] = 'value'` instead of `arr.push('value')`?

Comment: You're correct, push() should be better `randomClassList.push('box' + randomnumber);`